# AJP URL encoding

Tags: java, apache, urlencode, mod-proxy

I am having an issue with URL encoding. When I am executing URL on browser, server is encoding it again and again, however the url is already encoded to UTF-8.

```
eg. http://test.com:80/?gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fclosewindow.xyz.com&modal=true

I am getting - https://test.com/?gotoUrl=http%253A%252F%252Fclosewindow.xyz.com&modal=true
```

I am running my application on HTTPS and redirecting any request on 80 to HTTPS secure port 443. This problem only occurs if I send request on port 80 and server is redirecting it to secure port 443. If I make request on secure port 443, this problem does not occur.

Following is my tomcat configuration,

```
<Connector port="8080" 
           protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="5000" 
           compression="on"
           compressionMinSize="128"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,text    /json,
                                 application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/json" 
           enableLookups="false"
           maxPostSize="4096"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
       redirectPort="8443"

/>
<Connector  port="8009" 
            protocol="AJP/1.3" 
            URIEncoding="UTF-8"
/>

<Connector
   protocol="HTTP/1.1"
   port="8443" maxThreads="200"
   scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
   keystoreFile="/path/keystore" keystorePass="password"
   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

My environment is like Apache2.2 in on the front and tomcat7.x is connected via AJP with Apache server.

I dig into this issue and I found out that the issue is down to AJP that is using iso-8859-1, however tomcat & Apache are working fine and using UTF-8 encoding. Is there anyway to set encoding to UTF-8 in AJP? I am using mod_proxy_ajp.

Thanks in advance. I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: It would be good to know, which tomcat version you are using.

Comment: @Reboot I am using 7.0.26 version of tomcat. This is happening on uat environment, however i can't reproduce it locally. The only difference is uat environment resides behind akamai servers.

Comment: If you have additional information your should try to improve the question by adding it. The information that it only happens with Akamai servers could help others to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Reboot and EJP, I found out the issue is with AJP, I have modified my question. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the browser is doing it. It doesn't make sense for Tomcat to be doing it. Tomcat would be *decoding,* not encoding. Try it in the browser with no encoding at all.

Comment: When tomcat sends a redirect it has to encode the URL in the HTTP header, if it has been decoded before generating the redirect.

Comment: @Reboot Exactly, and the result of decoding plus encoding isn't a double encoding, is it?

Comment: You wrote Tomcat would not be doing any encoding, which is not correct, if it decodes the URL and sends a redirect. If the encoding does not work correctly and encodes the wrong input this could be an issue of Tomcat.

Comment: @Reboot No, it would be an issue with the original wrong encoding.